# Scale an entire html page under a certain width

Tags: html, css, viewport

This seems like a simple problem that I might be over thinking.

I have a page that scales down nicely using CSS, but I need to prevent it from wrapping text under a width of 360px.  The idea for this was to just use the same proportions of the page at a width of 360px, but "zoom out" in a sense using the viewport.  Using the viewport meta tag to set this is causing an issue with 320px wide phones (iPhone 5):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, min-width=360px, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I was doing this in conjunction with setting a min-width on the actual html of this page and the body tag, but the content under widths of 360px now require you to scroll sideways to see the entire page, or pinch and zoom out.

```
 html, body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 360px;
 }
```

Is there a simple answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

you could set the font-size of the box to a percent based value so it scales down with the rest of the page if thats the element preventing it to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent text from wrapping with [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```css
body {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
</p>
```

If using `white-space` on `<body>` mangles too much of your text you can create a utility class and apply to elements as needed.

```
.text-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```